# How to get a previous page from elasticsearch using search_after?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

I'm trying to create fast pagination with ElasticSearch. I have read this doc [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-after.html) about `search_after` operator. I understand how to create a "forward" pagination. But I can't realize how to move to the previous page in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the API doesn't have a search previous, you have this workaround.

It's easy to move backward and I had to do it as well. Just keep track of it in variables in whatever language you're using.

I indexed an object with the searches with a pointer to keep track of where I was in the data.  For example:

```
var $scope.search.display = 0;
var $scope.searchIndex = {};
var data = getElasticSearchQuery() //This is your data from the elastic query 
if (!$scope.searchIndex[$scope.search.display + 10] && data.hits.length > 0) {
    $scope.searchIndex[$scope.search.display + 10] = data.hits[data.hits.length - 1].sort;
}
```

If you have 'next' and 'previous' buttons, then in your POST request for elastic just assign the search_after parameter with the correct index:

```
$scope.prevButton = function(){
  $scope.search.display -= 10;
  if($scope.search.display < 10){
    $scope.search.searchAfter = null;
  }
  if($scope.searchIndex[$scope.search.display]){
    $scope.search.searchAfter = $scope.searchIndex[$scope.search.display]
  }
  $scope.sendResults(); //send the post in an elastic search query
};

$scope.nextButton = function() {
  $scope.search.display += 10;
  if($scope.searchIndex[$scope.search.display]){
    $scope.search.searchAfter = $scope.searchIndex[$scope.search.display];
  }
  $scope.sendResults(); //send the post in an elastic search query
};
```

That should get you on your feet. The 10 is my size, meaning I have a pagination of 10 results.

Answer (score 13):

In a project we are working on we’re going to simply reverse the sort direction and then use `search_after` as if it was a `search_before`.

This is a late answer, but it’s a little bit better than having to keep track of results on the application. For that specific scenario the Scroll APIs (that I don’t know if it was available at the time) should be more suited.

Comment: Nice, this answer solved my problem when I consider using Redis to cache the previous page(It hard to control when users retrieve too deep page), and we limit user skip page number at once.

Comment: TY for this... It seems counter-intuitive, but we found that it does solve the problem!

Comment: In the latest version of ElasticSearch (`v7.16`), it is recommended to use `search_after` API instead of the older scroll API. Refer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html